# Not able to read ZipInputStream returned by ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipEntry) method

Tags: java, file, zip

I am trying to read extract a given file from zip file. Zip file contains directories & sub-directories as well. I tried Java7 nio file apis but since my zip has subdirectories as well, I need to provide complete path to extract the file, which is not suitable in my scenario. As I have to take filetobeextracted input from user. I have been trying below code for it but somehow read method of ZipInputStream not reading any contents to buffer. On debugging I found out that ZipEntry object value is null inside ZipInputStream due to its read method simply returns -1.But now I am stuck as I am not able to figure out how that value is being set for it.

```
try(OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("filetoExtract");) {
    zipFile = new ZipFile("zipFile");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            String entryName = entry.getName();
            String fileName = entryName.substring(entryName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            System.out.println(i++ + "." + entryName);
            if (searchFile.equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) {
                System.out.println("File Found");
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
                ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[9000];
                int len;
                while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                out.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Error opening zip file" + ioe);
}
```

Please advice what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

EDIT:
After debugging little more I found out that ZipFile class has inner class of similar name(ZipFileInputStream). So it was creating object of it rather than the outside ZipFileInputStream class. So I tried out below code and it worked out well. But I don't quite understand things here, what has happened. If someone could help me logic behind the scenes would be really great.

```
//  BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new 
//BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
//ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
InputStream zin= zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line is unnecessary, as `zipFile.getInputStream(entry)` already returns an `InputStream` that represents the decompressed data. Therefore there's no need (or in fact it's wrong) to wrap that `InputStream` in yet another `ZipInputStream`:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

Comment: Yeah figured it out after spending some more time. Thanks